# Finding path between given pair of nodes in a unweighted, undirected graph

Tags: data-structures, graph

->Given graph can have around 100,000 nodes. 
->The edges between these nodes can be stored in adjacency list or adjacency 
  matrix. (Although I think adjacency list will be a better choice due to the 
  larger number of nodes). 
->Each pair of nodes has only one path between them.(So a graph with n nodes has 
  n-1 edges)  
->We are given a set consisting of pairs of vertices . We have to find out path 
  between each of these pairs. How to go about it in the most efficient way 
  possible.

Comment: See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59680/all-pairs-shortest-paths-in-trees) related discussion.

Comment: Given your constraints, you have the choice between breadth first search and depth first search. Do a little research and decide which you want to implement.